# Postman returns status 500 regardless of which JEE exeption do I use

Tags: java, spring, exception, jax-rs

I'm developing a spring boot app with a simple @RestController.

Here's the code snippet that bugs me.

```
  else if (validators.isCommentValid(submission) == false)
  throw new WebApplicationException("comment field is empty", 400);
  //throw new BadRequestException("Comment field cannot be empty");
  //throw new HTTPException(400);
```

The idea behind it: when comment field is empty, return 400 status (Bad Request).

I've tried multiple JEE (based on avax.ws.rs) exceptions, and they work fine when it comes to relaying message etc, but the status returned by postman is always 500.

Not sure what am I missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define your own exception and annotate them

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="comment field is empty")
```

See more [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exatly what I did (I also added @ControllerAdvice to keep them organised) and it works like a charm.